# How to set a Python path so that modules are found?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, pip, boto

I'm trying to run my boto script but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named boto.swf.layer2
```

According to pip freeze I have boto installed so I'm wondering what has gone wrong here.

My Python path is as follows:

> ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

My boto path is as follows:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/__init__.pyc
```

Does this mean it is some sort of error to do with the Python path? I'm really lost about how to debug this.

Comment: Looks like it's not a problem with the path, but with a missing module or a wrong module name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'd verify you can at least import boto:

```
import boto
print boto.__file__
```

Verify that this is in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/__init__.pyc`.

If that works then I'd check your boto version:

```
import boto
print boto.__version__
```

The specific module you're trying to import was added to boto in 2.7.0 so you'll need at least that version.